# android dialog box issue

Tags: android

I have an issue in android development.
I want to display Dialog Box when the application is launched before loading
and launching the activity.

or you can say I want to show the dialog on launcher after the launch of my
application.

Comment: Please search stackoverflow a bit before putting question.. you will get the answer4

Answer (score 0):

Why not show a dialog in `onCreate` of your `MAIN` activity?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider having a `InitActivity`  that does what @Teja Kantemneni does : launching a dialog and launching your own "real first activity" when user clicks on the right button.

Alternative :
I would also try to do it from the application class itself, but I am not sure of the result.

Create an application class, reference it in the manifest file, override onCreate and show your dialog. But honestly, I think it will already be too late and your main activity already launched at this point.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

You can show your dialog in your `onCreate` event in your startup activity.

You can then run your main code process once the user has confirmed the dialog (ie. capture the event and process your main code)

All this can be done in your `onCreateDialog`